# How to perform Web Push for a Web App over LAN

Tags: web-applications, push-notification

I am trying to build an on-premise web application hosted on a local server. Basically this app will display data stored in a local backend server (and the data is collected from some local IoT devices with a set frequency). I want to create a push notification when there is a new set of data received in the backend server.

I used pywebpush but chrome blocks my push notification for some reason (I believe it's because I am using local IP address?) Can anybody give me some pointers on **how I can enable push notification for an on-premise web application hosted on a local server?**

Thank you!